# The requirement is, the output will print one number followed by a character then a number and so on

Tags: java

I have am assignment suppose there is a string 11234aBcD the out put should be 1a1B2c3D4 and I am unable to do it, First and the second output I have done. And I have to do using java.

I am adding my code:

```
  package Testx;

  import java.util.Arrays;
  import java.util.Comparator;
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Test3optmz {

  public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner gaba = new Scanner( System.in ); 
    String variable;
    System.out.print("Enter String:");
    variable = gaba.nextLine();
    SeparateGaba(variable);

   }
    public static void SeparateGaba(String str) 
    {
    String Catch_num = "";
    String Catch_let = "";
    String upper="";
    String lower="";
    String holdl="";
    String holdn="";

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
    {
           char a = str.charAt(i);
           if (Character.isDigit(a)) 
           {
                 Catch_num = Catch_num + a;
           } else 
           {
                 Catch_let = Catch_let + a;
           }     
    } 

    System.out.println("FIRST OUTPUT:"+Catch_num+Catch_let);// i am separating the numbers and alphabets 

    for(int j=0;j <Catch_let.length();j++)
    {
         char x = Catch_let.charAt(j);
         if (Character.isUpperCase(x))
         {
                upper += x;
         }
         else 
         {
               lower += x;
         }
    }

    char[] num = Catch_num.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(num);
    String n =new String(num);

    char[] ordr = lower.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(ordr);
    String alfa1 =new String(ordr);

    char[] ord = upper.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(ord);
    String alfa =new String(ord);

    String t= alfa1 + alfa;

    char [] fin = t.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(fin);
    String fal = new String(fin);

    Character[] chars = new Character[fal.length()];
    for (int f=0; f < fal.length();f++)

        chars[f] = fal.charAt(f);

        Arrays.sort(chars, new Comparator<Character>()
        {
        public int compare(Character c1, Character c2)
        {
            int cmp = Character.compare(
                    Character.toLowerCase(c1.charValue()),
                    Character.toLowerCase(c2.charValue())
                );
            if (cmp != 0) return cmp;
            return Character.compare(c1.charValue(), c2.charValue());
        }
        });

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(chars.length);
        for (char c : chars) sb.append(c);
        fal = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("SECOND OUTPUT= "+n+fal);// now i am arranging the alphabet in ascending order avoiding capital and small ex 1234eBaC it will come as 1234aBce  

       }
       }
```

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. Include what you have tried so far.

Comment: sir there is the code i am working on

Comment: Your code looks very complicated. Think about what you need to do: find the next digit in the string, and append it to the output; then find the next non-digit in the string, and append it to the output; repeated until you've exhausted the input string.

Comment: for (int x=0; x < test1.length();x++)
      {
       char a= test1.charAt(x);
       char b= test1.charAt(x);
       StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder(a);
       StringBuilder sc = new StringBuilder(b);
       if(Character.isDigit(a))
       {
        st.append(a);
        get = st.toString();
        System.out.println("test="+get);
       }
       else
       //if(Character.isLetter(b))
       {
        sc.append(b);
           cot=sc.toString();
           
        System.out.println("test2="+cot) ;
       }
       
       
      }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well thanks for not helping me out i helped my self

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Test4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner gaba = new Scanner( System.in ); 
    String variable;
    System.out.print("Enter String:");
    variable = gaba.nextLine();
    SeparateGaba(variable);

    }
   public static void SeparateGaba(String str) 
    {
    String Catch_num = "";
    String Catch_let = "";
    String upper="";
    String lower="";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
    {
           char a = str.charAt(i);
           if (Character.isDigit(a)) 
           {
                 Catch_num = Catch_num + a;
           } else 
           {
                 Catch_let = Catch_let + a;
           }     
    } 

    System.out.println("FIRST OUTPUT:"+Catch_num+Catch_let);

    for(int j=0;j <Catch_let.length();j++)
    {
         char x = Catch_let.charAt(j);
         if (Character.isUpperCase(x))
         {
                upper += x;
         }
         else 
         {
               lower += x;
         }
    }

    char[] num = Catch_num.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(num);
    String n =new String(num);

    char[] ordr = lower.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(ordr);
    String alfa1 =new String(ordr);

    char[] ord = upper.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(ord);
    String alfa =new String(ord);

    String t= alfa1 + alfa;

    char [] fin = t.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(fin);
    String fal = new String(fin);

    Character[] chars = new Character[fal.length()];
    for (int f=0; f < fal.length();f++)

        chars[f] = fal.charAt(f);

        Arrays.sort(chars, new Comparator<Character>()
        {
        public int compare(Character c1, Character c2)
        {
            int cmp = Character.compare(
                    Character.toLowerCase(c1.charValue()),
                    Character.toLowerCase(c2.charValue())
                );
            if (cmp != 0) return cmp;
            return Character.compare(c1.charValue(), c2.charValue());
        }
        });

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(chars.length);
        for (char c : chars) sb.append(c);
        fal = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("SECOND OUTPUT= "+n+fal);
       /*GABA come on let seeeeeeeee*/
        try
        {
        for(int i=0;i<n.length();i++)
        {
            char a= n.charAt(i);

            System.out.print(a);

            for(int j=0; j<fal.length();j++)//1
            {
                char b = fal.charAt(j);
                if(j>=i)
                {   
                System.out.print(b);
                    break;
                }
            }
            }

           }
           catch(Exception e)
         {
       System.out.println("Your letter length should match with char len");
        }

       }
      }


       Enter String:14a5Bc
       FIRST OUTPUT:145aBc
       SECOND OUTPUT= 145aBc
       THE out put i was looking for --->1a4B5c
```